# Heat equation with non-homogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I am struggling with the following problem and am looking for some guidance.

> Find the solution to the 1-D heat equation given the following conditions:
>
> A sphere with radius 0 < r < a with initial temperature f`[r]` and surface temperature `Phi[t].z` 
>   The boundary conditions for `u[r, t]` are:
>
> ```
> u[0, t] == 0
> u[a, t] == a Phi[t]
> ```
>
> The initial condition is:
>
> ```
> u[r, 0] == r f[r]
> ```

```
heqn = D[u[r, t], t] == k*D[u[r, t], {r, 2}];
bc1 = u[0, t] == 0;
bc2 = u[a, t] == a*[Phi][t];
ic = u[r, 0] == r*f[r]; 
sol = DSolve[{heqn, ic, bc1, bc2}, u[r, t], {r, t}];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Mathematica `DSolve` can't solve heat PDE in 1D with boundary conditions that is time dependent. ps. why do you write `[Phi][t]` instead of `Phi[t]` ? Or is this a copy/paste thing?

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a copy and paste error. Is there another function you would suggest?

Comment: I suppose a "by hand" solution would be helpful. If you're willing, that is. It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> I suppose a "by hand" solution would be helpful. If you're willing,
>   that is. It would be appreciated

Ok, here it is

Solve
\begin{equation}
u_{t}=ku_{rr}\qquad t>0,0<r<a\tag{1}
\end{equation}
With boundary conditions
\begin{align*}
u\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\\
u\left(  a,t\right)    & =a\phi\left(  t\right)
\end{align*}

And initial conditions
$$
u\left(  r,0\right)  =rf\left(  r\right)
$$
Since the boundary conditions are not homogeneous, the first step is to
convert them to homogeneous. This is done using a reference function which
needs to only satisfy the boundary conditions. This reference function can be
seen to be $v\left(  r,t\right)  =r\phi\left(  t\right)  $. Now we write
$$
u\left(  r,t\right)  =w\left(  r,t\right)  +v\left(  r,t\right)
$$
Where $w\left(  r,t\right)  $ satisfies the PDE but with homogeneous B.C.
Substituting the above into (1) gives
\begin{align}
w_{t}\left(  r,t\right)  +r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)    & =kw_{rr}
\nonumber\\
w_{t}\left(  r,t\right)    & =kw_{rr}-r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \tag{2}
\end{align}
With boundary conditions
\begin{align*}
w\left(  0,t\right)    & =0\\
w\left(  a,t\right)    & =0
\end{align*}
The solution to the homogeneous PDE $w_{t}\left(  r,t\right)  =kw_{rr}$ with
the above boundary conditions is easily found and known. The eigenvalues are
$\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}\right)  ^{2},n=1,2,\cdots$ and
eigenfunctions $\Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)  =\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}r\right)  $. Let the solution to (2), using eigenfunction expansion be
\begin{equation}
w\left(  r,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  r\right)  \tag{2A}
\end{equation}
Substituting the above back into (2) gives
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)
=k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
r\right)  -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
Where $q_{n}\left(  t\right)  $ are the Fourier coefficients of $r\phi
^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  $ which are found by
$$
r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)
\Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)
$$
Applying orthogonality using $\Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)  $ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{a}r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)  dr  &
=\int_{0}^{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(
r\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)  dr\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}\left(  t\right)  \int_{0}^{r}\Phi_{n}\left(
r\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)  dr
\end{align*}
But $\int_{0}^{a}\Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)
dr=\int_{0}^{a}\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{m\pi}
{a}r\right)  dr=\frac{a}{2}$ for $n=m$ only,  and the above becomes
$$
\frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(
s\right)  dr=q_{m}\left(  t\right)
$$
Substituting the above back into (3) gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)
=k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
r\right)  -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\phi^{\prime
}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)  dr\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(
r\right)
$$
But $\Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  r\right)  =-\lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
r\right)  $ and above simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  r\right)
+k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  t\right)  \lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
r\right)    & =-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}
r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(  r\right)  dr\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  r\right)  \\
C_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  +kC_{n}\left(  t\right)  \lambda_{n}  &
=-\frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{m}\left(
r\right)  dr\\
& =-\frac{2}{a}\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \int_{0}^{a}r\sin\left(
\frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\\
& =-\frac{2}{a}\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \frac{\left(  -1\right)
^{n+1}a^{2}}{n\pi}\\
& =-2a\phi^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n\pi}
\end{align*}
This is first order ODE in $C\left(  t\right)  $. The solution is
$$
C_{n}\left(  t\right)  =e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}C_{n}\left(  0\right)
+2ae^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}
\phi^{\prime}\left(  \tau\right)  e^{k\lambda_{n}\tau}d\tau
$$
From (2A)
$$
w\left(  r,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}
C_{n}\left(  0\right)  +2ae^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}
}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}\phi^{\prime}\left(  \tau\right)  e^{k\lambda_{n}\tau}
d\tau\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
u\left(  r,t\right)    & =w\left(  r,t\right)  +v\left(  r,t\right)
\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}C_{n}\left(  0\right)
+2ae^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}
\phi^{\prime}\left(  \tau\right)  e^{k\lambda_{n}\tau}d\tau\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  +r\phi\left(  t\right)  \tag{4}
\end{align}
At $t=0$ the above becomes
\begin{align*}
rf\left(  r\right)    & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  0\right)  \sin\left(
\frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  +r\phi\left(  0\right)  \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left(  0\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)
& =r\left(  f\left(  r\right)  -\phi\left(  0\right)  \right)
\end{align*}
Hence $C_{n}\left(  0\right)  $ is the Fourier sine coefficients of
$\ r\left(  f\left(  r\right)  -\phi\left(  0\right)  \right)  $
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{2}C_{n}\left(  0\right)    & =\int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)
-\phi\left(  0\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\\
C_{n}\left(  0\right)    & =\frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)
-\phi\left(  0\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr
\end{align*}

Substituting this into (4) gives the final solution as
\begin{align*}
u\left(  r,t\right)    & =r\phi\left(  t\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(
e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\left(  \frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)
-\phi\left(  0\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\right)
+2ae^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}
\phi^{\prime}\left(  \tau\right)  e^{k\lambda_{n}\tau}d\tau\right)
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  \\
& =r\phi\left(  t\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  e^{-k\lambda_{n}
t}\left(  \frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)  -\phi\left(
0\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\right)
+2a\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}\phi^{\prime}\left(
\tau\right)  e^{-k\lambda_{n}\left(  t-\tau\right)  }d\tau\right)  \sin\left(
\frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  \\
& =r\phi\left(  t\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\left(
\frac{2}{a}\int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)  -\phi\left(  0\right)
\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\right)  \sin\left(  \frac
{n\pi}{a}r\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2a\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}
{n\pi}\int_{0}^{t}\phi^{\prime}\left(  \tau\right)  e^{-k\lambda_{n}\left(
t-\tau\right)  }d\tau\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)
\end{align*}

Or

\begin{align*}
u\left(  r,t\right)    & =r\phi\left(  t\right)  \\
& +\frac{2}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-k\lambda_{n}t}\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}
{a}r\right)  \left(  \int_{0}^{a}r\left(  f\left(  r\right)  -\phi\left(
0\right)  \right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  dr\right)  \\
& +\frac{2a}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n+1}}{n}
\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}r\right)  \int_{0}^{t}\phi^{\prime}\left(
\tau\right)  e^{-k\lambda_{n}\left(  t-\tau\right)  }d\tau
\end{align*}

Where $\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{a}\right)  ^{2}$.

I can use `NDSolve` to verify the above solution and comparing them. But I do not have values for your `a,f[r],phi[t]` to do that. If you have these, I could try to do that.